# How can I set Application State expiration?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Asp.Net application. For performance reason, some data is stored in Application State, like Application["MyData"] = myData;
Can I configure it to make the data get cleared regularly?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by refreshed? assigned a new value?

Comment: Maybe you want to store the data sessionwise then?

Comment: By "refreshed" I meant clearing the data stored. I fixed the phrase.

Comment: I cannot store it in Session, as my data is something globally used.

Comment: Application variables are globally used as well.

Comment: @FahadJameel "Application variables are globally used as well" - that is why I used Application and not Session.

Comment: then why dont you use session variables? set a expiration time for it, and assign every user who access your website that session variable.

Comment: I guess I may need to do that... If you edit your answer with this suggestion, I will mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just like variables, hence the name Application Variables. You can just reassign them to a new value.

```
Application["MyData"] = myData;
///Do something.
...
..
.
Application["MyData"] = myNewData;
```

Edit:

Application variables are specifically designed to last the lifetime of the application and not expire until the application closes. What you can do is assign every user a session variable who accesses your application and make it expire when you want.

Comment: But I need it to be done regularly. E.g. Session State has expiration time. I wonder if there is something similar for Application State.

Comment: Session state variables expires after the session time is over. Application variables expire after the application is closed.

Comment: Yes, and this is the problem. I just wondered if there is any way to set Application expiration time explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it explicitly , two ways

Application state is in IIS in the worker process application pool.  timeout settings here would do it

otherwise in c#

```
ApplicationPool.ProcessModel.PeriodicRestart.Time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

//or based on idle.  just play around with ApplicationPool. items

ApplicationPool.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout = 600000;
```

Comment: Where is this supposed to be set in a .net api? Startup.cs? Global.asax.cs?

Comment: well i got a negative score.  why would u ask?

should i code it for you?

Comment: for .net api, it has a global.aspx file, you can try App_Start\WebApiConfig   in your Register method too.  why dont you try before you ask.